# Reading csv file, having numbers and strings in one column

Tags: r, csv

I am importing a 3 column CSV file. The final column is a series of entries which are either an integer, or a string in quotation marks.

Here are a series of example entries:

```
1,4,"m"
1,5,20
1,6,"Canada"
1,7,4
1,8,5
```

When I import this using read.csv, these are all just turned in to factors.

How can I set it up such that these are read as integers and strings?

Thank you!

Comment: Figured out my problem. Kind of similar to yours. My column contained rows with either strings or integers like yours. String values were being read as "" and integers were being read correctly. When placing quotes around the string as you did and around the integers, each was read correctly from the csv. I'm still not sure the reason for this but seems to have worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not possible, since a given vector can only have a single mode (e.g. `character`, `numeric`, or `logical`).

However, you could split the vector into two separate vectors, one with numeric values and the second with character values:

```
vec <- c("m", 20, "Canada", 4, 5)

vnum <- as.numeric(vec)
vchar <- ifelse(is.na(vnum), vec, NA)

vnum
[1] NA 20 NA  4  5

vchar
[1] "m"      NA       "Canada" NA       NA
```

Comment: Andrie you said the same thing as me but better.

Comment: @user718281, to read as strings, not factors, use read.csv(...,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Comment: Thanks Andrie.

One thing I am not quite sure how to do though, is how do I go from the csv file to the vector. As in, it is my understanding that read.csv outputs a matrix, not a vector.

Comment: `read.csv` outputs a `data.frame`. There are several ways to index a column (vector) of a data.frame.  For example, by column number: `dat[, 3]`

Comment: Andrie,

Sorry for the ignorance, but this is not working for me. When I do as.numeric on a row from the dataframe, it is giving me numbers for each factor, rather than the actual integers.

Do you know how I might be able to fix that?

Comment: @user718281 Two things.  1) set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when you create the `data.frame`.  2) See `?as.factor` where you will find the following advice to convert a factor to numeric: `as.numeric(as.character(x))` or preferably `as.numeric(levels(x))[x]`

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT** *Despite the OP's decision to accept this answer, @Andrie's answer is the preferred solution. My answer is meant only to inform about some odd features of data frames.*

As others have pointed out, the short answer is that this isn't possible. `data.frame`s are intended to contain columns of a single atomic type. @Andrie's suggestion is a good one, but just for kicks I thought I'd point out a way to shoehorn this type of data into a `data.frame`.

You can convert the offending column to a list (this code assumes you've set `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`):

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection("1,4,'m'
1,5,20
1,6,'Canada'
1,7,4
1,8,5"),header = FALSE,sep = ",")

tmp <- as.list(as.numeric(dat$V3))
tmp[c(1,3)] <- dat$V3[c(1,3)]
dat$V3 <- tmp

str(dat)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ V1: int  1 1 1 1 1
 $ V2: int  4 5 6 7 8
 $ V3:List of 5
  ..$ : chr "m"
  ..$ : num 20
  ..$ : chr "Canada"
  ..$ : num 4
  ..$ : num 5
```

Now, there are all sorts of reasons why this is a bad idea. For one, lots of code that you'd expect to play nicely with `data.frame`s will not like this and either fail, or behave very strangely. But I thought I'd point it out as a curiosity.

Comment: As atrocious as this is, I am debating the ethics of coming up w/ something worse.  :)

Comment: Hmm, actually, this is not reproducible for me.  The values of V3 are 5,1,4,2,3, and classes are int, num, int, num, num.  Resolution: `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.

Comment: @Iterator Thank you for reminding me; I should be more careful about writing SO answers in a clean R session.

Answer (score 2):

No.  A dataframe is a series of pasted together vectors (a list of vectors or matrices).  Because each column is a vector it can not be classified as both integer and factor.  It must be one or the other.  You could split the vector apart into numeric and factor ( acolumn for each) but I don't believe this is what you want.